# My buttons are not redirecting to specified pages using react js? (I just started learning react) (Using old react version)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So, the problem is when I am trying to click Home in navbar its not redirecting the page to Textform component and when I am clicking about in navbar its not redirecting to about us page, but when i alter the url manually like adding localhost:3000 with "/about", its perfectly working.[image: Here is the code].
[image: Here is the app,when I clicked on about link]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8woYf.png)

I tried everything like altering the links and surfed the net but no solution resolved it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your answer with codeblock instead of images of code as [per the guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router-dom go check there

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#defining-routes

You need to specify your links as related to each other. Just read the documentation and you will get it.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="teams" element={<Teams />}>
      <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
      <Route path=":teamId/edit" element={<EditTeam />} />
      <Route path="new" element={<NewTeamForm />} />
      <Route index element={<LeagueStandings />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route element={<PageLayout />}>
    <Route path="/privacy" element={<Privacy />} />
    <Route path="/tos" element={<Tos />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="contact-us" element={<Contact />} />
</Routes>
```